# Ajax file upload with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I grabbed this code online(sanwebe.com) and I'm trying to use it as the basis for a "flyer wizard" where our customers will be able to upload their company logo onto a flyer and then print, but I can't quite get it to work. It keeps saying "error uploading file!" and doesn't display the photo. I've tried numerous file types which are all included in the accepted filetypes. The two primary files that I think may have the issue are index.php and/or processupload.php. There's an online demo that seems to work fine uploading an image and displaying it, but the version I downloaded doesn't work. I called godaddy and had the recommended settings (in the comments in the processupload.php file)  in the php.ini file updated and also restarted our server, but still no luck.

Link to online demo (that works):       http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-image-upload-progressbar/

Link to tutorial/download/forum page:        http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery/comment-page-1#comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around some more and found there were more than one "example code" download pages with a tutorial, and I had downloaded the wrong one without the code to actually display the image. Below is the link to the correct one. It works great.

http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php

Answer (score 0):

I think can be a permission problem so your server doesn't allow to upload files.

If you are using apache you can create a new group with both the apache user and FTP user as members and then make the permission on the upload folder 775. This should give both the apache and FTP users the ability to write to the files in the folder but keep everyone else from modifying them.

Comment: Hi Del, Thank you for your answer. We have a fully managed server with godaddy and I called them and had the php.ini file updated to allow file uploads and the following suggestions from comments inside the "processupload.php" file:

Comment: /*
 Note : You will run into errors or blank page if "memory_limit" or "upload_max_filesize" is set to low in "php.ini". 
 Open "php.ini" file, and search for "memory_limit" or "upload_max_filesize" limit 
 and set them adequately, also check "post_max_size".
 */